# How to implement getbootsrap.com/css purple banner

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On the website getbootstrap.com/css there is a purple banner at the top of the page.

Has this been achieved with any of the bootstrap components?

The closest thing I can see is a "panel"
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

I would like to do a similar layout but am new to bootstrap and now 100% how.

Comment: the styling is custom.. but the DOM elements are default.. it is a parent `div` with a `.container` inside.. the background color and padding on the parent div is what makes it look purple. you can see this by rightclicking on the the purple section and choosing 'Inspect Element'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS:

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .bs-docs-masthead {
                padding: 80px 0;
            }
        }

        .bs-docs-masthead, .bs-docs-header {
            position: relative;
            padding: 30px 15px;
            color: #cdbfe3;
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
            background-color: #6f5499;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#563d7c),to(#6f5499));
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#563d7c 0,#6f5499 100%);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#563d7c 0,#6f5499 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#563d7c 0,#6f5499 100%);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#563d7c', endColorstr='#6F5499', GradientType=0);
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
        }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="bs-docs-masthead" id="content" role="main">
            <div class="container">
                Your Data
            </div>
        </div>
```